# Jasmine Testing Angular File Upload

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test the file upload feature in Angular, via my controller. I have logic that will check the file size, and then when the image is loaded, I want to do run additional logic.

When I run the test case, I get the error `TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

I am wondering- What is the proper way to test this?

I am using Jasmine 2.7, Angular 1.6.5, Karma 1.7.0, and Karma Jasmine 1.1.0.

Here is my test case:

```
it('should do something', function() {

    let event = {
        target: {
            files:{
                0:{
                    name: "test.png",
                    size: 20000000,
                    type: "image/png"
                }
            },
        }
    };

    ctrl.processFile(event);
    spyOn(window, 'Image')
    expect(ctrl.fileTooBig).toBeTruthy()
});
```

Here is the controller code it is trying to test:

```
vm.fileTooBig = '';
vm.processFile = function(event) {
    console.log("event", event)

    file = event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(fileEvent) {

        //is the file bigger than 10MB?
        if (fileEvent.total > 10000000) {
             vm.fileTooBig = true;
        }

        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function(evt) {
               // do something
            }

        };

    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};

$(document).on("change", "input[type=file]", function(event) {
    vm.processFile(event);
});
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this by now?

Comment: No, I am still stuck on this testing issue